# how to understand the relation between uintptr and struct?

Tags: go

I have learned code like the following

```
func str2bytes(s string) []byte {
    x := (*[2]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    h := [3]uintptr{x[0], x[1], x[1]}
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))
}
```

this function is to change `string` to `[]byte` without the stage copying data.

I try to convert num to reverseNum

```
type Num struct {
    name  int8
    value int8
}

type ReverseNum struct {
    value int8
    name  int8
}
func main() {
    n := Num{100, 10}
    z := (*[2]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&n))
    h := [2]uintptr{z[1], z[0]}
    fmt.Println(*(*ReverseNum)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))) // print result is {0, 0}
}
```

this code doesn't get the result I want.
Can anybody tell my about

Comment: 7. It is simply unsafe.

Comment: @kostix, Sorry, I'm new to go. I just want to learn about the principle behind the package  unsafe. The code pasted in the question just get me confused. I won't write code like that in real project. Could you please paste the left 6 points on your comment? Thank you very much, they can help me a lot!

Comment: Oh, that wasn't me, that was @Volker; my comment was a pun on his :-)

Comment: When you are new to Go: Stay wide away from a) unsafe b) reflection and c) the empty interface. You cannot learn anything from package unsafe which you could not learn in much simpler ways. (Somebody deleted 1. through 6.)

Answer (score 3):

That's too compilcated.
A simpler

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Num struct {
    name  int8
    value int8
}

type ReverseNum struct {
    value int8
    name  int8
}

func main() {
    n := Num{name: 42, value: 12}

    p := (*ReverseNum)(unsafe.Pointer(&n))

    fmt.Println(p.value, p.name)
}
```

outputs "42, 12".

---

But the real question is why on Earth would you want to go for such trickery instead of copying two freaking bytes which is done instantly on any sensible CPU Go programs run on?

Another problem with your approach is that IIUC nothing in the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#System_considerations) guarantees that two types which have seemingly identical fields *must* have identical memory layouts. I beleive they *should* on most implementations but I do not think they are required to do that.

Also consider that seemingly innocuous things like *also* having an extra field (even of type `struct{}`!) in your data type may do [interesting](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct) [things](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard) to memory layouts of the variables of those types, so it may be outright dangerous to assume you may *reinterpret* memory of Go variables the way you want.

Comment: "But the real question is why on Earth would you want to go for such trickery instead of copying two freaking bytes which is done instantly on any sensible CPU Go programs run on?" there's no need to attack OP here. It's obviously a contrived example, they wanted to know why/how `unsafe` works, this is likely not an actual use case.

Comment: @Adrian, oh, I did not intend to mount any sort of personal attack, really. I think if I were to do that, the phrase you've cited would be the single one in my answer; and in such a case, I'd just post a comment and/or outright voted to close the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> ... I just want to learn about the principle behind the package unsafe.

It's an [escape hatch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escape%20hatch).

All strongly-typed but compiled languages have a basic problem: the actual machines on which the compiled programs will run do not have the same typing system as the compiler.<sup>1</sup>  That is, the machine itself probably has a linear address space where *bytes* are assembled into *machine words* that are grouped into *pages*, and so on.  The operating system may also provide access at, say, page granularity: if you need more memory, the OS will give you one page—4096 bytes, or 8192 bytes, or 65536 bytes, or whatever the page size is—of additional memory at a time.

There are many ways to attack this problem.  For instance, one can write code directly in machine (or assembly) language, using the hardware's instruction set, to talk to the OS to achieve OS-level things.  This code can then talk to the compiled program, acting as the go-between.  If the compiled program needs to allocate a 40-byte data structure, this machine-level code can figure out how to do that within the strictures of the OS's page-size allocations.

But writing machine code is difficult and time-consuming.  That's precisely why we have high-level languages and compilers in the first place.  What if we had a way to, within the high-level language, *violate* the normal rules imposed *by* the language?  By violating specific requirements in specific ways, carefully coordinating those ways with all other code that also violates those requirements, we can, in code we keep away from the usual application programming, write much of our memory-management, process-management, and so on in our high-level language.

In other words, we can use `unsafe` (or something similar in other languages) to deliberately *break* the type-safety provided by our high level language.  When we do this—when we break the rules—we must know what all the rules are, and that our specific violations here will function correctly when combined with all the normal code that *does* obey the normal rules *and* when combined with all the special, unsafe code that breaks the rules.

This often requires help from the compiler itself.  If you inspect the `runtime` source distributed with Go, you will find routines with annotations like `go:noescape`, `go:noinline`, `go:nosplit`, and `go:nowritebarrier`.  You need to know when and why these are required if you are going to make much use of some of the escape-hatch programming.

A few of the simpler uses, such as tricks to gain access to string or slice headers, are ... well, they are still *unsafe*, but they are unsafe in more-predictable ways and do not require this kind of close coordination with the compiler itself.

To understand how, when, and why they work, you need to understand how the compiler and runtime allocate and work with strings and slices, and in some cases, how memory is laid out on the hardware, and some of the rules about Go's garbage collector.  In particular, the GC code is aware of `unsafe.Pointer` but not of `uintptr`.  Much of this is pretty tricky: see, e.g., https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoUintptrVsUnsafePointer and the link to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19135, in which writing `nil` to a Go pointer value caused Go's garbage collector to complain, because the write caused the GC to inspect the *previously stored* value, which was invalid.

---

<sup>1</sup>See [this Wikipedia article on the Intel 432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432) for a notable attempt at designing hardware to run compiled high level languages.  There have been others in the past as well, often with the same fate, though some IBM projects have been more successful.

Comment: Excellent answer (as usually).